# Are laptop screens with the same interface cross compatible?

Tags: laptop

The screen on my laptop just cracked and I'm looking to replace it. I did find a new panel for sale that is described to be for my exact laptop model, however I also red up on laptop screens and it appears that my laptop has a 40 pin LVDS connector which is supposedly used by quite many laptops and screens.

The lightbulb moment was this question - are these connectors just like DVI or HDMI, as in, universal? Could I hook up just any 17.3" 40 pin LVDS screen and have it work?

The vast majority of screens that are the same size and connector seem to be 1600x900, but I did read that the connector supports up to 1920x1080 and I found a few for sale too. In theory the video card shouldn't have any issue with the resolution as I've hooked it up to even a 4k desktop monitor through the HDMI connector.

Comment: I've seen many LVDS connections and many of them have *similar* pinouts, but are subtly different. You would need to get the datasheet for the panels you have and what you are replacing with to be sure they match.

Comment: It's best to stick to part numbers your laptop model was originally offered with _(usually models are offered with a range of panels, such as good, better, best)_, else you'd need to verify the pinouts as @Mokubai mentioned, as connecting a connector with a different pinout could not only fry the screen, it could fry the motherboard.